# Embed NHibernate assemblies in ASP.NET website

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate

A friend and I are working on a ASP.NET website and that friend decided he wants to employ the NHibernate framework for ORM. I have **zero** experience with using non-standard frameworks, he has more experience though not in .NET but in Java.

The problem is he committed his changes to the project to a subversion repository after he  got it all working locally, but when I update, VS gives 7 errors and a warning about not finding the NHibernate assembly references. He just added the references to the project. There is a `bin` folder in which some `dll.refresh` resides (this file causes the warning) that points to a full path name on my friends computer (bad thing in other words).

He and I would like to know, what is he doing wrong? How can we embed the DLLs in the project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He needs to commit the original assemblies to subversion from wherever he referenced them in the project. For example he could create a `lib` subfolder to the project in which to put all third-party assemblies. Then reference from this lib folder and commit it to subversion. Then when you checkout you will get this lib folder and the application will compile locally because all the necessary dependencies are part of the source control.

Answer (score 0):

- You can put the dlls you need in ~\bin and check them in
- You can put the dlls on the level above, say in External Assemblies folder, and edit .redresh files to use relative path
- But I recommend you, first, convert your project from Web Site Project to Web Application Project, what brings a lot of benefits, including compiling web site in a single assembly, and second, use [NuGet](http://nuget.org/) (VS package management extension) to reference, control and maintenance any 3rd party libraries and other dependencies via it.